# Why is there a 14th Noah?

Tags: d-gray-man

This question could contain spoilers.

In Chapter 187, it was stated that after the Millennium Earl was killed, the remaining twelve Noahs repopulated the world - That means that there were only 13 Noahs. However, Nea Walker is referred to as "The 14th Noah". Where did he came from?

Comment: Maybe he wasn't counted as a Noah because he was disowned

Comment: @ChetterHummin: But that was around 7000 years later ...

Comment: Ah, my bad :) I haven't seen the series. Just read the wiki...

Comment: If you count Bondomus (Jasdero/Devit) as one apostle/person, then Nea (the so-called "14th") is the 13th apostle.

Comment: @Krazer: In chapter 187, Jasdero and Devit were counted as two apostles, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @looper They are listed as two apostles in the CharaGray character book, too~

Answer (score 2):

Unanswered in the manga as of now, but it is entirely possible that there are 14 Noah and the Earl only mentions 13 (including himself) because the 14th apparently dislikes the Earl, as he wants to dethrone him and take his place. Chapter 218 hints that a "Mana D. Campbell" may be responsible for the existence of the 14th, although i can´t really call the Earl in his current state of mind a reliable source.

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible that the Millennium Earl was trying to hide the existence of the 14th Noah from the others for as long as possible, as until they found out about Allen, I don't recall any of them mentioning anything about the 14th, and they couldn't sense him yet as he wasn't awakened.

However, it's always possible that it could've been an error in translation, but I doubt it, as the official versions are, well, official.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the Millenium Earl was killed leaving the present 12 Noah remaining, I'll assume that one of these 12 is the new Millenium Earl. This new Millenium Earl states that in total there were only 13, and it should only be 13 by what I've seen in the anime and manga.
So my guess is the 14th Noah, Nea, is the reincarnation of the 1st Millenium Earl, the one that was killed by the other Noah, and for that reason he came back in another form as the 14th so he can kill the Millenium Earl and take his place back as head of the family.
Really silly answer, just guessing.